# Need help finding a Fantasy Book with a sword wielder and sight sharer

Tags: story-identification

Thank you for taking time to look at my enquiry.

I am trying to find a book i read some 10 years ago (2007) but i did not have the sense to see when it was published at that time.

All i could remember was the main characters were a boy and a girl. One day, a girl found a chest and inside was a glove which she wore, and it got 'bonded' with her. The glove is actually a sword made out of light when the wearer activates it. Together with her is the boy, who has this gift to share sights with other animals or people. i.e he can see through the animal/person. not unlike Starks children from GoTs.

In addition the other small part i could remember was the boy's uncle or some relative is actually the bad guy in the book and share the same gift as the boy. The ending was the boy blinding his uncle by shooting a arrow to kill the crow that his uncle was sharing the sight with at that time, thus blinding him.

If anyone know the title of such a book please share. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am almost certain that you must've read this series: "The Darkest Age series".

The first part of the series - [The Coming of Dragons](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/712725.The_Coming_of_Dragons) happens to be published on March 1st 2007 and contains two characters who obtain powers very similar to that you describe.

> In COMING OF DRAGONS, Edmund and Elspeth received strange and powerful gifts that would lead them on a dangerous quest. Edmund has the vision of the Ripente - he can reach inside the minds of others and see what they see. Elspeth can draw upon the power of an enchanted sword and gauntlet when she is in danger.